# onClickListenner from RecyclerView not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm using a RecyclerView to show some info from Firebase, with kotlin in Android Studio.

But when I click on the RecyclerView, it return the position as -1, so the page that opens that item is always empty...

This is my code from setOnClickListener on the ViewHolder:

```
class CustomViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val titulo = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtTitle)
    val localizacao = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtDescription)
    //val urlPag = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.record_amount)
    //val descricao = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.record_date)
    val img = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageItem)

    init {
        view.setOnClickListener{
            val position: String = CustomViewHolder(it).bindingAdapterPosition.toString()
            val intent = Intent(view.context, NotificationActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("id", position)
                println(position)
            }
            view.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the fragment were the recyclerView is:

```
class InboxFragment : Fragment() {
    private var listData: List<Notifications>? = null
    private var adapter: MainAdapter? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false)

        val rv = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)

        rv.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        listData = ArrayList()

        val nm = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("notifications")
        nm.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (npsnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        val l: Notifications? = npsnapshot.getValue(Notifications::class.java)
                        if (l != null) {
                            (listData as ArrayList<Notifications>).add(l)
                        }
                    }
                    adapter = MainAdapter(listData)
                    rv.adapter = adapter
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
        })



        return view
    }
}
```

This is the adapter:

```
class MainAdapter(var listData: List<Notifications>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>(){

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listData!!.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        //create view
        val layoutInflater =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.inforow, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val ld: Notifications = listData!![position]
        holder.titulo.text = ld.titulo
        holder.localizacao.text = ld.localizacao
        Picasso.get().load(ld.img).into(holder.img)
    }
}
```

[image: This is my Firebase]

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that actually gets the data from the database.

Comment: If you use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: CostumViewHolder(it).bindingAdapterPosition -> bindingAdapterPosition remove CostumViewHolder(it)

Comment: @AlexMamo No...the only info i get on logcat is the position and it´s always -1

Comment: @CôngHải It worked! Thank you so much..could you please explain why it wasn't working?

Comment: hmm, CostumViewHolder(it) you create new view holder it not relate to current view holder